# Run an unprepared statement with Zend Db

Tags: php, zend-framework, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a LOAD DATA INFILE statement with a ZF 1.10.6 application. However, the Mysqli adapter reports that

> Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception:
>   Mysqli prepare error: This command is
>   not supported in the prepared
>   statement protocol yet in
>   /xxx/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php
>   on line 77

So I can't use this feature with prepared statements. However the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` creates a statement each time it queries the DB.

There is a bug filed in here about this issue:

http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-1398

It seems I can get the DB connection from the object directly with `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::getConnection()` however I find it a bit raw.

I was wondering if someone found an acceptable workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to ask the same thing as you. Since no one has answered yet, i would extend Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli (or which ever you are using) and create a method to run a method for an "unprepared" statement, something like queryWithoutPrepare($q). The body is pretty simple

```
return $this->getConnection()->query($q)
```