# Error while implementing 'lock table' in Zend

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, zend-framework

Following is my  code for implementing  lock to  a table

```
$defaultDb = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$defaultDb->query("LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE");
```

But iam getting an error

> exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Mysqli
>   prepare error: This command is not supported in the prepared statement
>   protocol yet'
>
> Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare('LOCK TABLES ..')

Can't we use lock in Zend ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Zend problem, rather Mysqli not accepting prepared statement for certain queries. See:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1398

and

[Run an unprepared statement with Zend Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598312/run-an-unprepared-statement-with-zend-db)

You will need to extend the adapter, or write your SQL directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.But still i didn't get a proper solution.Can you describe it little more?